# CoreData: Can I perform a method on a FetchRequest results as it searches?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `TableView` that lists very simple `CoreData` objects (they contain a name `String` and a couple of other fields).

I am using a `FetchedResultsController`, so my `TableView` currently uses 'fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)' to populate the cells.

In my code, I have a function that converts the `CoreData` object `.name` property into a different value (i.e. "dog" might become "cat").

I want to add a search to my `TableView`, but I want it so the user can also search for the **changed** values (i.e. they can search for "dog" or they can search for "cat").

Is there a `fetchRequest` property I can use to perform a `FetchResults` query/custom filter function simultaneously?

Comment: *dog might become cat*? What did you mean by saying this? Can you explain that?

Comment: Basically I perform a function on the string kept in Core Data (i.e. 'dog') and alter it to something else (i.e. 'cat', but it could also be a number). I want to be able to query for the new value it gets altered to as part of an NSPredicate, if possible.

I could just use an Array instead that contains the filtered/altered data after I've  queried for it, but I was wondering if I could have more control/filtering over the data I query for as part of the FetchRequest, before my TableView gets updated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't a solution to this using predicates (which can't use transient / computed values etc), so I ended up removing the FetchedResultsController, and doing my own filtering after my FetchRequests.